# Next-auth missing username (credentials-provider)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I try to learn next-auth in nextJs 13. I have credentials login with username and passowrd. From API I get status 200 if credentials are ok. Whole logic is in back-end. All I have to do is send req with credentials and if res.ok I need to save username to session and use it in main component. Now it doesn't work and don't why.

```
import type { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth'

import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials'


export const options: NextAuthOptions = {
providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
        name: "Credentials",
        credentials: {
            username: {
                label: "Meno:",
                type: "text",
                placeholder: "TB0XX"
            },
            password: {
                label: "Heslo:",
                type: "password",
                placeholder: "Heslo"
            }
        },
                       
         async authorize(credentials) {
             if (!credentials) {
               throw new Error('Credentials are required');
             }
       
             console.log(credentials);
       
             const res = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/login", {
               method: 'POST',
               body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
               headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
             })
       
             const user = await res.json()
             console.log(user);
             console.log(credentials.username)
             // If no error and we have user data, return it
             if (res.ok && user) {
               return { id: user.id, username: credentials.username, role: user.role }
             }
       
             // Return null if user data could not be retrieved
             return null
           }

    })
],
callbacks: {
    // Ref: https://authjs.dev/guides/basics/role-based-access-control#persisting-the-role
    async jwt({ token, user, profile }) {
        if (user) token.role = user.role
        console.log(user)
        return token
    },
    // UI view
    async session({ session, token }) {
        if (session?.user) session.user.role = token.role
        return session
    },
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The session callback is called whenever a session is checked. By default, only a subset of the token is returned for increased security. If you want to make something available you added to the token (like access_token and user.id from above) via the jwt() callback, you have to explicitly forward it here to make it available to the client. this is from next-auth callback docs.

If you need nick_name - you need to modify your session and jwt callbacks in your auth options

```
  callbacks: {
      async session({ session, token, user }) {
  if (session && session.user) {
    // @ts-ignore
    if (!session.user.role) {
      // @ts-ignore
      session.user.role = token.role;
    }
    if (!session.user.user_name) {
      // @ts-ignore
      session.user.user_name = token.user_name;
    }
  }
  return session;
},
async jwt({ token, account, profile, user }) {
  if (account) {
    token.role = user.role
    token.user_name = user.user_name;
  }
  return token;
}
```

}